# ToggleClass with animation both ways. Menu slide in and slide out

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, menu, slide

I am stuck, and I simple can't figure out what's the easiest way to solve this. I'm trying to make a simple slide in and slide out menu with this script:

```
$("#arrow").on("click", menuShowBtn);

function menuShowBtn() {
    console.log("menuShowBtn");
    $("#menu").toggleClass("menu_slut_pos");
    $("#arrow").toggleClass("arrow_rotate_again");
}
```

I have made a 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/znxqp94v/) to show you the problem. I simple need the animation to go both ways, so when toggle again the animation is reversed.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Since you're using CSS animations, you may be able to use `animation-direction: reverse;` to hide your sidebar. I'm not sure if there is a more elegant way, but that should work.

Comment: I have actually tried that, but i can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  var menu = $('.menu');
  menu.toggleClass('active')
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

.button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff0000;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:-350px;
  width: 350px;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}

.active {
  left: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="button">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your code, the animation is specifying the menu to go left from -350px to 0px only. The `toggleClass()` method returns to the original menu state without any animation whatsoever.

In my snippet, I have not added any `@keyframes` animations. The CSS `transition` property takes care of the slide.

Comment: Thank you, but i was looking to make the arrow rotate when toggle, anyway you could help me with that?

Comment: yeah sure...replace the `<span>` elements with your arrow and add code you wrote to animate the arrow in your example.